# final total method PHP result

Tags: php

I'm currently trying to create a final total method using PHP. So far I keep getting this error for the following code:

Notice: Undefined variable: finalTotal

The method does work and the final amount is calculated however I am not sure how to define the $finalTotal variable so no errors turn up. Any tips would be appreciated.

Here is the code

```
     $tot1=$row['productvalue']*$value; 

                       $finalTotal +=$tot1;
                     }
    echo $finalTotal;
```

Any tips are appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you initialize `finalTotal` before.

```php
$fintalTotal = 0;
```

Than, perform your actions.

Comment: Then define it in the actual scope.

Comment: PHP's variable scope is not block-based. Defining a variable inside a deeply nested if/whatever structure doesn't matter - it's still in scope within the function/containing script.

Answer (score 0):

What if you add like this

```
$finalTotal=0;
//your loop
$tot1=$row['productvalue']*$value; 
 // rest of code
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always good practice to initialize your variable, at least IMO.  In this case, to 0.